# Laravel 8 gates not working with Auth::guard

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, roles

Hey I am developing a project where I have roles and permissions for users and I am trying to protect my routes with the help of middleware by defining Gates but it's showing me `403| Not Authorized`. I can't understand what the actual problem is?

Into Category Controller

```
public function addcategory(AdminsRole $adminsroles){

   return view('add-category');

}
```

Into Routes

```
Route::get('/add-category', [CategoryController::class, 'addcategory'])->middleware('can:add-category')->name('addcategory');
```

Into AuthServiceProvider.php

```
$admin = Auth::guard('admin');

Gate::define('add-category', function ($admin, AdminsRole $adminsroles) {

    if($admin->user()->u_type != 'superadmin'){

        $adminRolescount = $adminsroles::where([
            ['admin_id', '=', $admin->user()->id],
            ['module', '=', 'categories'],
            ['add_access', '=', '1'],
        ])->count();
        return $adminRolescount;

    }else{

        return $adminRolescount = 1;

    } 

});
```

Comment: did you mean to return `adminRolesCount == 1`? Edit: Wait - why do you even set $adminRolescount? Why do you return a count? I'm confused :D

Comment: @Frank no it was not working as I have expected for so I tested with `adminRolesCount == 1` which is also not working

Comment: @Frank there is two types of admin `Superadmin` and `Subadmin` for Superadmin I want to  give them all access no restriction but for  Subadmin they need to go through the logic defined in gate.

Comment: How is AdminsRole $adminsroles passed into the gates function? Or even into addcategory? I don't see it defined in the route. Also - ensure to return bools so instead of the count just check for existence or at elast return $adminRolescount > 0 for non super admins and return true for superadmins. 
I'm not too much into Gates so someone else might be a better help here

Comment: @Frank Okay thanks

Comment: In your AuthServiceProvider.php you don't need to fetch the admin guard to pass it to the gate, since all you're doing with it is access the current user instance. Gates always receive a user instance as their first parameter so your `$admin` parameter would automatically contain the current user. Aside from that, you're not passing the `$adminsroles` parameter anywhere, but I don't think it's needed either. You can just query via the model inside your gate definition, e.g. `AdminsRole::where()`

Comment: @wblommaert can you show the codes about what you are saying...

Comment: @TeDeveloper I provided an answer with my suggestions for the gate definition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for can be simplified. The code in your controller and routes file does not need to be adjusted. I would however change your gate definition to the following:

```php
Gate::define('add-category', function ($user = null) {
    
    // Fetch user from custom guard
    $user = Auth::guard('admin')->user();

    // Check if a valid user instance was passed
    if (is_null($user)) {
        return false;
    }

    // Allow super admins to add categories regardless of AdminsRole existence
    if ($user->u_type === 'superadmin') {
        return true;
    }

    // Check if current user has a matching AdminsRole row with add_access permission
    return AdminsRole::where([
        ['admin_id', '=', $user->id],
        ['module', '=', 'categories'],
        ['add_access', '=', '1'],
    ])->exists();

});
```

Note that a gate always receives a user instance as their first parameter if there is a logged in user, you needn't supply this yourself. Additionally, you can query for the AdminsRole existence directly via the model, using the id of the user instance that is being checked and automatically supplied to the gate.

Comment: Hey I am not using the user table I have a separate table for users which is the admin table. And what if `return AdminsRole::where([
        ['admin_id', '=', $user->id],
        ['module', '=', 'categories'],
        ['add_access', '=', '1'],
    ])->exists();` this means if exist will return true and my middleware will allow me to enter the page right.

Comment: And if the user is not subadmin i.e is superadmin then true this means if true my middleware will allow me to enter the page right. And can we write multiple return true conditions in gate is it possible???

Comment: Can you update your question with information on how this admin table is connected to your login/authentication? Also yes, the `exists()` method will return a boolean value which is true or false depending on the query it finishes. In case of true, your middleware would indeed allow that user to view the page. I'll update my answer with some comments to clarify.

Comment: I am just not using the default authentication provided from laravel i have created a guard `admin` for me, where i am using the default login procedure provided in laravel documentation, just not using the users table i have created a separate table called admins table quite similar to the users table i did this because i need to use users table for the customers.

Comment: @TeDeveloper I've modified the answer to fetch the user from your custom guard, based on the info you've given me.

Comment: What you provided I have understood I want to know 1. can we write multiple return true conditions as you have shown is it possible??? 2. If any one of the conditions in the gates is true then my middleware will allow me to enter into the desired page right???

Comment: 1. this is possible and early return statements (which I used here) are a nice way to clean up your logic instead of having several if else blocks. 
2. correct, at any point if a true value is returned, the gate will allow access.

Comment: Okay, I have implemented what you have said but it is showing me the as usual error that was showing to me before `403| Not Authorized`??? Although the user has the permissions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236346/discussion-between-wblommaert-and-tedeveloper).

Comment: Hey I need to rush to do some work, can we discuss it tomorrow if you will

Comment: Sure, just hit me up in the chat via the link above :)

Comment: Hey, it is working for me. Thank You...!Can you help me it is showing laravel default `403| Not Authorized` template but i want to redirect it to dashboard i.e if not authorized then redirect to dashboard.

Comment: Glad to hear that! I suggest you either make a new question regarding your 403 redirect or use the chatroom above to explain what you want to do exactly. Comments aren't really the place to have discussions or ask new questions.

Comment: Okay Sure After One Hour